# Is there any way to solve the bug with BB-8's mission on D'Qar?

Tags: lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

I've finished the storyline on Lego Star Wars: The Force Awakens (PS4 version, if it makes a difference), and am now mopping up the extra tasks.  However, one of the BB-8 race missions on D'Qar is glitching out on me.  I switch to BB-8, start the mission, and a loading screen appears (with the mission's countdown timer at the top of the screen).  But the loading screen never leaves, so I can't do the mission - I wind up having to force-quit and restart the game in order to do anything else.

Here's [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9woE37Q2pI0) demonstrating what I mean.

Is there any known workaround?  Or am I just going to have to wait and hope for a patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do anything special, just went and did other things in game for a few days.  When I came back it had fixed itself.  Yay, I guess? :/